# JHipster: Entity dropdown is blank

Tags: angular, spring, jhipster

I imported the default JDL from the JHipster website, however, when I try to access the entity dropdown menu, it is blank, after I ran mvnw clean and closed the command prompt to refresh it, it still would not fix the issue. it works normally otherwise

Comment: Did you follow the instructions in your project's README.md? Dev or prod build? mvnw only or mvnw + npm? Did you read the docs:?https://www.jhipster.tech/using-angular/

Comment: I did, it did not fix it

Comment: How are you importing the .jdl/.jh?, is import successful? At the end of execution are you seeing any congratulation message in the log end? which database configuration are you using for your app?

Comment: I typed in the command "jhipster import-jdl jhipster.jh", I put JWT and MySQL

Comment: I had this happen this week. Creating the same app in a new directory solved it for me.

Comment: At the end of execution, are you seeing any congratulation message in the log end? Do you have Mysql installed? can you see tables created in Mysql? do you have jhiptser.jh

Comment: what it has todo with command prompt refresh or refresh? please paste log and *.jh/*.jdl file

Comment: Did you manage to solve this issue? I'm also facing the same issue. It seems its been around for years too! I've tried `./mvnw` and `npm start` in another terminal - still doesnt fix it.

Comment: I have same issue, lot of people having this same issue but no help in internet....